# .NET memory leak only in some environments

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, production-environment

I have a .net application which runs fine on local environment. But when it goes to production, the memory keeps increasing without going down anytime.

This, to me, seems like a finalizer thread blocked issue. Has anybody experienced this strange behavior only in certain environments?